# Изменение логики обновления webView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, webview

Необходимо изменить подход обновления страницы, проведя пальцем вниз, где обновление должно происходить в верхней части веб-представления, размер которого ограничен 100 пикселями.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mySwipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        setupWebView();
        setupGestureDetector();
        setupSwipeRefresh();
    }

    private void setupWebView() {
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebView(this));

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
                return super.onCreateWindow(view, isDialog, isUserGesture, resultMsg);
            }

        });

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);

        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView,true);
        }

        String ua = webSettings.getUserAgentString()
                .replace("; wv", "");

        int uaIndex = ua.indexOf("Version");

        ua = ua.substring(0, uaIndex)
                .concat(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .concat(ua.substring(uaIndex));

        webSettings.setUserAgentString(ua);

        webView.loadUrl("");


    }

    private void setupGestureDetector() {
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                if (e1 != null && e2 != null) {
                    if (e1.getY() <= 50 && distanceY < 0) { // check for swipe down at the top
                        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                        webView.reload();
                    }
                }
                return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private void setupSwipeRefresh() {
        webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (webView.getScrollY() == 0) {
                    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                webView.reload();
            }
        });

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                if (mySwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

............................................................

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

На данный момент стандартная логика SwipeRefreshLayout работает.

Что не так с кодом и разметкой? Как заставить его работать как надо?

Пожалуйста, помогите решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил сделать через RelativeLayout прозрачную область и навесить на неё

```
    (Ваша область).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event)
            {
                switch(event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        wv.reload();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Правда, это может дать не совсем желаемый результат, так как если вы хотите добиться обновления страницы как в современных браузерах, я думаю, нужно использовать другой подход...